# jsGrid : Adding a row using json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsgrid

How can simply add a row in jsGrid dynamically?

I am using reference code from  https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/blob/master/demos/db.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `insertItem` API method of the grid http://js-grid.com/docs/#insertitemitem-promise.

```
// insert item
$("#grid").jsGrid("insertItem", { Name: "John", Age: 25, Country: 2 }).done(function() {
    console.log("insertion completed");
});
```